# Браузер кеширует страницу для залогиненного пользователя и после logout отдает ту же кешированную версию

Tags: php, laravel, http, кэширование

Логинюсь под пользователем,захожу на несколько страниц
Затем разлогиниваюсь , захожу обратно на посещенные страницы
Браузер кеширует версию view когда я был залогинен и после logout продолжает отдавать версию для залогиненного пользователя.

Comment: Где данные пользователя храните, после логина?

Comment: Можете предоставить код, отвечающий за `logout`?